# Solving equation with sums and exponential

Tags: summation, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

I'm a bit stuck with the following equation which I have to solve for $K^T$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\exp(-K^Tx_i)x_i^T=P^T$$

Hope you can help! Thanks.
Joe

Comment: Are the $T$ superscripts supposed to be transposes?  Is the thing in the exponential then $\vec K \cdot \vec x$?  Or are the $T$s powers?  MathJax hint:  if you put a backslash before common functions you get the right font and spacing, so \exp x gives $\exp x$ in contrast to exp x which gives $exp x$

Comment: Hi yes the T are transposes

Comment: It looks like there is something wrong in the indexing.  The argument of the exponential needs to be a scalar, or maybe a square matrix, which is why I asked about the dot product.  Please check.  As written the left side is a number and the right is a vector (transpose)